# UIButton EXC_BAD_ACCESS after a second touch?

Tags: ios, uibutton, exc-bad-access

Every time I touch the UIButton with "Touch Up Inside" the second time the app crashes with EXC_BAD_ACCESS. I cannot find the problem and think everything is fine.

Here is my .h file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface AnleitungWebViewController : UIViewController {

    UIWebView *anleitungwebview;
    NSURL *pdfpfad_anleitung;
    NSString *aktuellesBild;
    NSString *nummer;
    IBOutlet UIActivityIndicatorView *indicator;
    IBOutlet UILabel *laden;
    IBOutlet UIButton *vor;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWebView *anleitungwebview;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIActivityIndicatorView *indicator;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *laden;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *vor;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSURL *pdfpfad_anleitung;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *aktuellesBild;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *nummer;

- (IBAction)zuruck:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)vor:(id)sender;


@end
```

And my .m file:

```
#import "AnleitungWebViewController.h"

@implementation AnleitungWebViewController

@synthesize anleitungwebview, pdfpfad_anleitung, indicator, laden, aktuellesBild, nummer, vor;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
    //NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:pdfpfad_anleitung];
    //[anleitungwebview loadRequest:request];

    //aktuellesBild = @"anl_30148_120701-de-001";

    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:aktuellesBild ofType:@"jpg"];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:path];

    NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
    [anleitungwebview loadRequest:request];
}

- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *) webView {

    [indicator startAnimating];
    indicator.hidden = NO;
    laden.hidden = NO;

}

- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *) webView {

    [indicator stopAnimating];
    indicator.hidden = YES;
    laden.hidden = YES;

}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

- (IBAction)zuruck:(id)sender {

    nummer = [aktuellesBild substringFromIndex:[aktuellesBild length]-3];

    int num = [nummer intValue];
    num = num - 1;

    if (num < 10) {
        nummer = @"00";
        nummer = [nummer stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", num]];
    }
    else if (num > 9) {
        nummer = @"0";
        nummer = [nummer stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", num]];
    }
    else{
        nummer = [nummer stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", num]];
    }

    aktuellesBild = [aktuellesBild substringToIndex:[aktuellesBild length]-3];
    aktuellesBild = [aktuellesBild stringByAppendingString:nummer];

    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:aktuellesBild ofType:@"jpg"];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:path];

    NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
    [anleitungwebview loadRequest:request];

    NSLog(@"%@", aktuellesBild);
}

- (IBAction)vor:(id)sender {

    NSLog(@"TEST");

    nummer = [aktuellesBild substringFromIndex:[aktuellesBild length]-3];

    int num = [nummer intValue];
    num = num + 1;

    if (num < 10) {
        nummer = @"00";
        nummer = [nummer stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", num]];
    }
    else if (num > 9) {
        nummer = @"0";
        nummer = [nummer stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", num]];
    }
    else{
        nummer = [nummer stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", num]];
    }

    aktuellesBild = [aktuellesBild substringToIndex:[aktuellesBild length]-3];
    aktuellesBild = [aktuellesBild stringByAppendingString:nummer];

    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:aktuellesBild ofType:@"jpg"];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:path];

    NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
    [anleitungwebview loadRequest:request];

    NSLog(@"%@", aktuellesBild);
}

- (void)dealloc {

    [anleitungwebview release];
    [laden release];
    [indicator release];
    [pdfpfad_anleitung release];
    [aktuellesBild release];
    [nummer release];
    [vor release];
    [super dealloc];
}


@end
```

Anyone with an idea?

Comment: have you tried to enable zombies? "EXC_BAD_ACCESS" is almost always a memory issue where you are sending a message to a released object.

Comment: You have 2 actions defined in your code, which one is causing the problem, *zuruck* or *vor*?

Comment: its the "vor" action, Now I enable "zombies" over Diagnostics and get this message: "-[CFString length]: message sent to deallocated instance 0xa245670"

Comment: I got it! I use everywhere self.aktuellesBild and self.nummer, I think after the first touch the variables are released...  Now with self. they directly access...

Answer (score 0):

You don't check the string length

```
nummer = [aktuellesBild substringFromIndex:[aktuellesBild length]-3];
```

Comment: What you mean with "check"? A NSLog or what?

Comment: for example [aktuellesBild length] = 2